# PriorityQueue sort is giving strange behavior on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, collections, priority-queue

I've MyQ class

```
class MyQ{
   Queue<Request> q = new PriorityQueue<Request>(7, new SortRequest());
   QueueStorage qStorage = new QueueStorage();

 public void addRequest(int siteId, int timeStamp){
    try{
            q = qStorage.readRequestQ();
            q.add(new Request(sId, tStamp));
            qStorage.writeRequestQ(q);
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
     //similarly deleteRequest() and showRequest() method follows.
   }
```

My **Request** class contains two fields `int id` and `int count` along with setters and getters.

**SortRequest** class is something like this:

```
 class SortRequest implements Comparator<Request>, Serializable{
   public int compare(Request r1, Request r2) {
           if(r1.getCount()!=r2.getCount())
                return new Integer(r1.getCount()).compareTo(r2.getCount());
           if(r1.getId()!=r2.getId())
                return new Integer(r1.getId()).compareTo(r2.getId());
           return 0; 
   }
 }
```

And QStorage class is something like:

```
 class QStorage{
      Queue<Request> readReqQ = new PriorityQueue<Request>(7, new SortRequest());

   public Queue<Request> readRequestQ() {
    try{
      FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("/home/winn/requestQ.ser");
      ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
      readReqQ = (Queue)ois.readObject();
             }
            catch(Exception e){
      return null;
            }
          return readReqQ;
       }

       public void writeRequestQ(Queue<Request> rq){
        Queue<Request> requestQ = rq;
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/home/winn/requestQ.ser"); 
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(requestQ);
        System.out.println("done");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
 }
```

And also I am storing this queue in file after every add/poll operation using Object input/output stream. While adding element I am first reading stored entries and then adding new entry and again storing it back.

Constraint is that id should be unique, count can be same/different for two or more ids.
So I'm performing sorting on count parameter, but in case if count is same then I should get the sort order such that lower id should precede higher one.

I tried initially this program on my linux system, where it was working properly and correctly giving sort order as per my expectation. But then somehow I deleted all class files and also created a new file for storing, and now same code(after recompiling) giving me completely strange results. Its not even sorting based on count parameter. Why this is so?

I then tried the same code on my windows 7 system, its again started producing correct results.
Why such a strange behaviour ?
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What code is giving what strange results, compared to what expectations?

Comment: Comparator code, its giving strange results. When first time I tried this code, it worked correctly and comparator sorted my list properly according to count parameter. But next time when I deleted all class files and recompiled the same code again, Its not at all performing the sorting. It may seems to you a foolish problem, but ya its happening with my linux system. I don't know why?

Comment: I then tried it on windows 7, its working properly and maintaining the sort order.

Comment: Please help me somebody.

Comment: You're not showing the relevant code: what code do you execute? What do you expect it to do, and what happens instead?

Comment: @JB Nizet Added the detailed class structure.

Comment: That doesn't answer the questions: what code do you execute? What do you expect it to do, and what happens instead?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't closing the ObjectOutputStream. I expect that you are getting a StreamCorruptedException or an EOFException instead of the behaviour you so vaguely describe. Or that you are ignoring such exceptions and proceeding with your code anyway.

Comment: Great..!! worked after properly closing input/output streams. Thanks a lot.

Comment: But I want to know one thing, does windows 7 environment performs all these things automatically? May be linux does not. Am I correct? Because my program was giving correct results when run on windows even when I didn't close these streams properly.

Comment: Your code must be a tangle of ignored exceptions for any if this to have occurred, so anything could have happened on Windows as well.